# Android set Album Thumbnail

Tags: android, insert, albumart

I have retrieved some cover art for an album (I have the id and a Bitmap) and now I want to set it into the MediaStore.

I tried a bunch of stuff:

```
private static final Uri ARTWORK_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

public static void writeArtwork(Context context, Bitmap bmp, int albumId) {
        ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ARTWORK_URI, albumId);
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "uri= " + uri);
        if (uri != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            LogUtil.i(TAG, "Bytes: " + bytes.length);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("album_id", albumId);
            values.put("_data", bytes);
            res.insert(uri, values);
        }
    }
```

This gives java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Invalid URI content://media/external/audio/albumart/5

Also I tried:

```
Uri artworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(artworkUri, album.getId());
OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outStream);
```

But this gives FileNotFoundException.

Comment: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/packages/apps/Music/src/com/android/music/MusicUtils.java

Found a solution in here.

Comment: I think link is down so here is the full answer in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7617143/396106