# How can i Change The embedded album art of an mp3 (etc) file?

Tags: android

How can i change the image or add an image? I am not talking about changing in the android database because that can be done from content resolver; I am talking about changing the embedded art.

I tried
[How can I update the album art path using contentResolver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504726/how-can-i-update-the-album-art-path-using-contentresolver)
and 
[how to set our image as artwork in a mp3 album in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590351/how-to-set-our-image-as-artwork-in-a-mp3-album-in-android) but they are just changing the values in the database which  i don't want
I also tried using "MY_ID3_For_Android" But that didn't help either because no functions are provided to change the album art,only functions are to change the other tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the ID3 Tag. I've been using this library:

https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic

Comment: I have added an answer ...i was too stupid ...a little bit of looking into the classes helped ..i will accept your answer though,because you tried to help :)

Answer (score 0):

MY_ID3_For_Android helps....

```
MusicMetadata ab;
                                        ImageData image;
                                        ab.addPicture(image);
```

Comment: > MY_ID3_For_Android helps....



Can you elaborate?