# How to update values in MediaStore.Audio.Albums table

Tags: android

I am queryng `MediaStore.Audio.Media` for a song ID, using the ID to find the album art URI, and then downloading the album art if the URI is null, and finally updating `MediaStore.Audio.Albums` with the new image URI. I am not able to figure out the last part.

Here I am getting the cursor  with `GetCursor()` method

```
private Cursor GetCursor() {

    Uri contentURI = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID};
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
    String order = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, projection, selection, null, order);// Run getContentResolver query
    return mCursor;
}
```

Here I am adding the album art URI to `songObject` with GetAlbumArtURI()

```
String[] albumID = {mCursor.getString(5)};
songObject.albumArtURI = GetAlbumArtURI(albumID);
```

Here is `GetAlbumArtURI()` method

```
private String GetAlbumArtURI(String[] albumID) {

    final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
            albumID,
            null
    );

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        String var = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
        //DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mCursor);
        mCursor.close();
        return var;
    }
    else {
        mCursor.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here I test if the `songObject.albumArtURI` is null, download the image, and record the URI in the meta data

```
if (songObject.albumArtURI == null){

    String anotherURI = downloadImageReturnURI();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART, anotherURI);

    // And now I don't know what to do

}
```

So now, how can I add the new URI back to ALBUM_ART column? Something along these lines?

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

The problem is that I am not trying to update values in `MediaStore.Audio.Media` but in `MediaStore.Audio.Albums`

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504726/how-can-i-update-the-album-art-path-using-contentresolver

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation - Content Provider Basics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html)

```
// Defines a new Uri object that receives the result of the insertion
Uri mNewUri;

...

// Defines an object to contain the new values to insert
ContentValues mNewValues = new ContentValues();

/*
 * Sets the values of each column and inserts the word. The arguments to the "put"
 * method are "column name" and "value"
 */
mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID, "example.user");
mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE, "en_US");
mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.WORD, "insert");
mNewValues.put(UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY, "100");

mNewUri = getContentResolver().insert(
    UserDictionary.Word.CONTENT_URI,   // the user dictionary content URI
    mNewValues                          // the values to insert
);
```

And this is probably the most important take away

> Many providers allow you to access a single row in a table by appending an ID value to the end of the URI. For example, to retrieve a row whose _ID is 4 from user dictionary, you can use this content URI:
>
> Uri singleUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,4);