# How to change Album Art using Content Resolver?

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, cover, albumart

Basically i want to change the album art of audio file in android.i am getting all the audio file by the following method:

```
    private void loadAudio() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = myContext.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long thisId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
            String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
            long albumId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
            String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
            final Uri ART_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ART_CONTENT_URI, albumId);
            songList.add(new songModel(thisId, title,artist,albumArtUri,data,albumId));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

I cannot use [Mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) as it only deals with .mp3 file.
What i am trying is to delete the path of the album art for the concerned audio from the media store and insert a new one as follows:

```
ContentResolver res = getContext().getContentResolver();
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = res.openInputStream(Uri.parse(path));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            albumartexists = false;
        }
        if (albumartexists)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "file exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getContext().getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),id), null, null);
        }
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("album_id",id);
        values.put("_data",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Thumbnail/"+targetFileName);
        Uri newuri = res.insert(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"), values);
        if(newuri==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "nwure is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getContext().getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"),id), null, null);
            newuri = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"), values);
        }
```

this code works for some file while for some file,when the albumart is changed with it several song's albumart is changed.
I don't know where is the mistake.
please help me with it!
Don't know where is the problem with the code or something else.

this code has been referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504726/how-can-i-update-the-album-art-path-using-contentresolver/7617143#7617143)

edit: I am using JaudioTagger it is working fine but changing one audio's album art changes for all pls help

Comment: *I don't know where is the mistake. please help me with it! Don't know where is the problem with the code or something* but, you didn't even mentioned what is the problem ?

Comment: @Ravi pls check the edit it's written that changing one albumart causes change in several others.

Comment: Can you be specific ? which method ?